# DataTable does not get assigned

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datatable

When `button_click` event is fired. I get `DataTable` from method and assign it to `DataTable` defined in class, but this `DataTable` setting in nothing. If I bind `DataTable` to `GridView` it show data.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  TestClass test = new TestClass();
  DataTable _table = new DataTable();

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      _table = test.getTable();
     //displaying table
      GridView1.DataSource= _table;
      GridView1.DataBind();
    }
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //does not displaying table 
      GridView2.DataSource= _table;
      GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

When I want get some data from `_table`, it have nothing. What's wrong?

**Update:**
Thanks all, and especially [Darren Davies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280410/darren-davies), problem been in Postback. When Button2_Click event happens _table assign _table = new DataTable(), and therefore _table no more reference to table returned by method getTable().

Comment: Are you sure getTable() return data ?

Comment: I debugged it and _table have rows [count = 54], but then I click button2 row have count = 0.

Comment: @AlbertGore - most likely a Postback has occured.  You'll need to call `getTable` again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will only bind correctly if Button1 is clicked before Button2.   Otherwise `_table` will not be populated.

You should check that `_table` has data or call the `getTable` method inside the `Button2_Click` event handler:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _table = test.getTable();
   GridView2.DataSource= _table;
   GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          _table = test.getTable();
         //displaying table
         GridVieuw1.Datasource = null;
         GridView1.DataSource= _table;
         GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

Also you must do this at buuton 2

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

              _table = test.getTable();
             //displaying table
             GridVieuw2.Datasource = null;
             GridView2.DataSource= _table;
             GridView2.DataBind();

            }
```

Otheriwse the table is empty at button 2, so you have to press button 1 to fill it

Maybe that can do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your `DataTable` like

```
DataTable _table = new DataTable();
```

Then, when you click your button 1:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _table = test.getTable(); // <- here
 //displaying table
  GridView1.DataSource= _table;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

you are assigning your `DataTable` to a **different** instance. 
You have to debug and check that your method `getTable` is returning a valid `DataTable` (and if you want to see your data, make sure that it contains data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises when you do not press button 1 before button 2. You should generalized your data binding like this:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  TestClass test = new TestClass();
  DataTable _table = new DataTable();

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      FillDataTable ();    // <----------- See this function call

     //displaying table
      GridView1.DataSource= _table;
      GridView1.DataBind();
    }
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      FillDataTable ();    // <----------- See this function call

      //does not displaying table 
      GridView2.DataSource= _table;
      GridView2.DataBind();
    }

    private void FillDataTable()
    {
         if(_table.Rows.Count == 0) 
           _table = test.getTable();
    }
}
```

It would a wise way to fill table once, instead of filling on every button click and write it down in every button click event.